# Add bash to base Linux Kernel?

Tags: bash, shell, embedded

We have a proprietary SBC (Single Board Computer) type of platform that is a large sized scale Raspberry Pi essentially. It is ARM based and uses Linux Kernel v3.# as its base. This isn't an Ubuntu question but I know Ubuntu does have ARM support in some versions so maybe there is shared knowledge.

We use a provided BSP (Board Support Package) to get interfacing to it through UART and can give it very basic Linux commands with the $sh.

It's frustrating as I cannot use most of the known bash commands I am used to.
Is there anyway to increase functionality by 'adding' bash to different Linux platforms?

Comment: I'm curious what "known bash commands" you might be referring to?  (Most of the commands that you run through a bash command line prompt aren't "bash commands" at all, but external utilities.  There is a [fairly short list](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) of commands that are built in.)

Comment: Such systems are often limited in resources. Sounds like you are running a variation of BusyBox. If not, busybox can be configured to be very bash like.

Comment: @Wildcard Oh cool. I don't have a definitive list but most general ones like the binary executables found in the path directory like fdisk or chmod etc.

Comment: @jdv It isn't running busybox but that is a possibility for the platform we are using.

Comment: You are talking about wanting additional commands and utilities that are available in common Linux distributions, not "bash commands"

Comment: Is it because these utilities are not installed, or that your shell cannot find them, or that they do not execute correctly for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Consider **dash** (Debian Almquist Shell) as a light-weight alternative:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash

(but this will require you to review/edit your existing **bash** scripts for *bash-isms*)